# How to create vertical Scroll View in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new to ios development. I am trying to create a vertical ScrollView in a Xamarin iOS application.

Below is my code for a horizontal ScrollView

```
using System;

using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using CoreGraphics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        ScrollingButtonsController ();
    }

    UIScrollView scrollView;
    List<UIButton> buttons;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //MyScrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
        //MyScrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(CGFloat.width, CGFloat.height);          

        //end
        nfloat h = 50.0f;
        nfloat w = 50.0f;
        nfloat padding = 10.0f;
        nint n = 100;

        scrollView = new UIScrollView {
            Frame = new CGRect (0, 100, View.Frame.Height, h + 2 * padding),
            ContentSize = new CGSize ((w + padding) * n, h),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        };

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            var button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            button.SetTitle (i.ToString (), UIControlState.Normal);
            button.Frame = new CGRect (padding * (i + 1) + (i * w), padding, w, h);
            scrollView.AddSubview (button);
            buttons.Add (button);
        }

        View.AddSubview (scrollView);

        //UIScrollView scrollView;
    //scrollView = new UIScrollView (
    //      new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
    //  View.AddSubview (scrollView);



    }
    public void ScrollingButtonsController ()
    {
        buttons = new List<UIButton> ();

    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }


}
}
```

I want to create a vertical scrollview and add some scrollable Text Views. Any idea on how can to do this?

I would be grateful if you can specify in detail how can I get the elements in my Main.storyboard file with structure scheme as per below to scroll:

```
-Scroll View
--label
---Image View
---Text View
--label
---Image View
---Text View
--label
---Image View
---Text View
--label
---Image View
---Text View
--label
---Image View
---Text View
```

and more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set ScrollView Content Size Height, larger than it's frame height.So it will scroll up/down. Width of scroll view should be the same as its content width, so it won't scroll right/left.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this. I used many tutorials both with and without code. The best way to do the scrolling is the following:

- Add the scrollview (left, right, up, down constraints)
- Add whatever you want
- The tricky part is to set 2 constraints:

  1) horizontal space to container, where container is the scroll view (do this with you wider element)

  2) vertical space to container, where container is the scroll view (do this with your last element)

While your screen becomes taller, the vertical constraint will increase your scroll view. No code needed, just the proper constraints.

In your example you have to:

- set up, left and right constraints to your first label
- add vertical constraints amongst all your labels
- add the final vertical constrain between your final textview and the scrollview (the textview is possible to need a height constraint)

If your elements don't fit the screen in Xcode, use freeform size to make your controller bigger (this applies only to xcode, not on your actual program)

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting & readability of your text.